# Counting in base n

Tags: numbers

**Edit:**
When teaching math to English only students they are often unaware that the numbers from 11 to 19 do not follow the normal rule for saying numbers. It is fun to point this out while leaning about counting in other bases. I have often used my made up words below to help students think about counting in base 16 and then it becomes clear to them that the numbers 11 to 19 are odd words. All I'm trying to do here is reach out to a group that undoubtedly knows many different languages in a hope to find some better made up words that might even come with some justification for their usage.

Here is my simplified minimum question:

Is there a single word for "16" in any language?
Is there a single word or set of words for "16*16" or 16^2 or 256?

**Original question and background understanding of counting**

This is intended to be a fun question. I have asked it in other groups but I have never gotten a real good answer. I a scientist and not a linguist as I'm sure you will be able to tell as you read my post.

**The Question**

How do I say numbers in different bases?

Here is an example using  the root words "hex" and "hexsquare" for base 16.

3C6 -> three hexsquare "C" hex six

This is similar to saying a base 10 number as
  243 -> two hundred four "tee" three

**Lots of background**

I think we all agree that the concept of a number is independent of what
  base we are in and how we say it in our favorite language. The names of the
  numbers from {0 -> (n-1)} are arbitrary. Also there are special words for numbers that are used sometimes like score, dozen etc.

There are two ways of saying a number: 1) Read out the digits one by
  one. However before this can work the two people need to agree on two
  things, The order the digits will be read (little ending or big ending) and
  the base. (The number 100101101001 could be in base 18 I just needed to use
  ones and zeros)

2) Use our base ten words. Any number in any base can be said in our base
  ten words. "A" is ten. However this requires the user to convert the
  non-base 10 number to base ten to say it. (Without much work say: 3A4G8, it
  is in base 17) (If you do not think we use base ten words to say numbers
  try this: Write down the numbers 0 through say 20 in base 2 then say the
  numbers as you point to them and you will notice that your words do not
  reflect the change in the written symbols. However if you do the same with
  a list of base ten numbers you will notice that your words change in step
  with the changing symbols.)

It is most likely true that there is not a defined way to say numbers in
  other basses in a formal way. Now as you know us scientist types are more
  than happy to make up new words when we need them. So let me explain the
  concept more clearly and I invite you to help me make up some words.

When you see the "(10 | 16 | n)" just read one of the items in the list. I
  would suggest on the first read you read the first one, "10"

First let me explain what it means to count in a base. I'll do this in base
  (10 | 16 | n). We count objects up to (9 | 15 | n-1) then when we add the
  next object we say that we have 1 set of (10 | 16 | n). We set that aside
  then count up to (9 | 15 | n-1) again. Then when we add in one more object
  we say, we now have 2 sets of (10 | 16 | n) objects. At some point we will
  get up to (9 | 15 | n-1) sets of objects and (9 | 15 | n-1) additional
  individual objects. When we add one more object we will have (10 | 16 | n)
  sets of (10 | 16 | n) objects which is a total of (10*10 | 16*16 | n*n)
  objects. We would write that number as 100 for all the bases. But remember
  the number 100 represents a different about in the different bases.

When we count in base (10 | 16 | n) we need written symbols and words for
  the numbers 0 to (9 | 16 | n-1). Once we get up to our first set of (10 |
  16 | n) we need a word for that set.

In base ten that word sounds like "tee". So I can say the number 68 as
  "six-tee-eight". This means that I have 6 groups of "tee" (10) objects and
  8 individual objects. For larger numbers in base ten we have hundred so we
  can say the number 352 as "three-hundred-five-tee-two". Let me write the
  number more mathematically. 352 = 3*100 + 5*10 + 2 = 3*10*10 + 5*10 + 2. In
  the second one I explicitly wrote 100 as 10 groups of 10 or 10*10. Now it
  is clear how the words map to the numbers.

The 16 symbols used for base 16 are 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e,f. It is
  clear what words to use for 0-9 but what should we say for "a" through "f"?
  I'm happy with just saying the letter like "a" but not ten or
  "one-tee". The number after "f" in base 16 is 10. We can not call this ten!
  The word we use here needs to be a word for "a set of 16". In my first post
  I used the word "hex". (But this also makes me think about base 6.) In base
  16 the number right after ff is 100. This is 16 sets of 16. In my first
  post I used the word "hexsquare".

I'm most interested in base 16 and base 2 so I need words for:

16 ->

16*16 ->

16*16*16->

etc

2->

2*2->

2*2*2->

etc

Example: Lets make up some words for the base 16 
  16-> hex

16*16 -> dex

16*16*16-> rex

Now I can say the base 16 number e42f as "e rex 4 dex 2 hex f"

I'm sure that many of you have a much better command of the language and
  may be able to come up with some good words to use so I can start saying
  base 16 numbers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with linguistics.

Comment: You could perhaps research how people in cultures with non-decimal number systems pronounce them, but just asking about that would be too broad.

Comment: Where is the right place to ask this?

Comment: Not every question has a place to be asked on the Stack Exchange network. This one seems to be pretty subjective too, which means it may not be appropriate anywhere. You could ask here how existing languages with Duodecimal systems pronounce them (it's more common than hexadecimal). You could ask on [programmers.se] what are the common ways to pronounce hexadecimal numbers. But I don't think thinking up new ways will be appropriate anywhere.

Comment: A propos the newly stated question, a number of languages have single words for "16", such as English, Norwegian, German, Dutch, Russian, Ukrainian, Finnish, Hungarian, Basque. I don't believe any language has a single word for 256. Apart from powers of 10, I don't believe any language has a lexical item for any number over 20, Check http://lingweb.eva.mpg.de/numeral/ for a large inventory of systems.

Answer (score 1):

You first have to distinguish between actual native numbers, vs. invented ~ imposed systems. English is basically base 10, and so is Arabic, and so on, so there's a bunch of things that you can ask about how people read these base 10 number strings (the basic result is that people gravitate towards binary groups if the string is long enough). Once we meet the Monwaingi in outer space, we can investigate their base-6 numbering system. Natural / existing numbering systems are where it matters what the base is, because there is an actual acquired grammar for such systems.

You could also investigate the behavior of adults reading hex strings, though you have to mind the demographics (CS professionals may behave differently from your average lab hacker). I think you would find that people parse long-enough strings into binary pair, using the same strategy that they use for reading street addresses. (That means that 4578 is "45" "78" and not "4,578"). Digits A-F have to be read as letter pairs, so "183F" would most likely be read as "1" "83" "F", since we avoid mixing English numbers and letter name if possible. But you may find quite a number of behaviors, depending on profession and familiarity with reading hex strings. There's really no market for octal so no realistic chance of testing -- except if you can coopt a psych class instructor into providing you a bunch of undergrad subjects. People are quite unlikely to read "3C6" as "three hexsquare c hex six", rather than just "three c six" -- the latter is much simpler.

There is a (decent) sci-fi book that I read decades ago which involved some improvement of human cognition where the author went though a description of how we started slowly saying "one zero zero one..." and ended up develop a linguistic shorthand with expressions like "otter tot" -- can't remember the book. If you know what I mean, you could see what he had to say. But this is strictly science fiction / conlaning, or the stuff of psych experiments, and you can't develop a native numbering system in a psych experiment.

Notice that nobody reads 543638158741648773686798718786416875478 as "five hundred forty three undecillion six hundred thirty eight decillion....". Given the nature of human cognition, precision and comprehension are at odds. If you need to report the exact value, read the string pairwise from left to right. If you need to convey the rough magnitude, say "about half a duodecillion" and hope that your colleague knows what a duodecillion is.

Answer (score 0):

So, I gather, you're not interested in describing how people say numbers.  Instead, you want to tell them how they ought to say numbers.  This is similar to the approach of the astronomers who recently decided that we ought not to call Pluto a planet.  It is generally contrary to linguistic thought of the last century or so, and I am really not in sympathy with your effort.  I've never liked being told what to do.

But try to have fun, anyway.

Comment: Isn't he rather asking the community what would be convenient ways to say numbers, rather than trying to impose his opinion?

Comment: No I want to take how people say numbers in base ten and find a way to generalize it to other bases.

Comment: But to what ends do you want to do this?!